Не работает очистка ошибок при переносе с обработчика в функцию
Это учебное задание. Первоначально, clearValidation был в обработчике редактирования учетки, все корректно работало:
openButtonPopupEdit.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nameInput.value = profileTitle.textContent;
    jobInput.value = profileDescription.textContent;
    openModal(popupEdit);//открыть модальное окно
    clearValidation(formEditProfile, validationConfig);//очистить ошибки валидации при успешной загрузке
}); 

При повторном открытии  модального окна все ошибки очищались. Ревьюер сделал замечание:

Функционал сброса ошибок валидации данной формы следует перенести в хэндлер сабмита формы (в цепочку then), так как ошибки валидации следует очищать только при успешном сабмите формы

я удалила clearValidation из обработчика и перенесла в функцию editAccount согласно замечанию ревьюера:
function editAccount(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); 
    renderLoading(true, buttonFormSubmit);
    patchProfileRequest(nameInput.value, jobInput.value)
    .then(() => {
        profileTitle.textContent = nameInput.value;
        profileDescription.textContent = jobInput.value;
        closeModal(popupEdit);
        clearValidation(formEditProfile, validationConfig);//очистить ошибки валидации при успешной загрузке
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Ошибка при загрузке данных: ${error}`);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        renderLoading(false, buttonFormSubmit);
    }) };

как итог очистка ошибок перестала работать, при повторном открытии модального окна ошибки остаются. Но, при этом в консоли ошибок нет, .then также выполняется. В чем может быть проблема, как перенести clearValidation в editAccount, чтобы все при этом корректно работало?
Фрагмент разметки:
<div class="popup popup_type_edit popup_is-animated">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <button type="button" class="popup__close" aria-label="закрыть окно"></button>
      <h3 class="popup__title">Редактировать профиль</h3>
      <form class="popup__form" name="edit-profile" novalidate>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        name="name" 
        class="popup__input popup__input_type_name"
        id="name-input" 
        placeholder="Имя" 
        required 
        minlength="2" 
        maxlength="40"
        pattern="^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ\s\-]+$"
        data-error-message="Разрешены только латинские, кириллические буквы, знаки дефиса и пробелы">
        <span class="popup__error name-input-error"></span>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        name="description" 
        class="popup__input popup__input_type_description" 
        id="description-input" 
        placeholder="Занятие" 
        required 
        minlength="2" 
        maxlength="200"
        pattern="^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ\s\-]+$"
        data-error-message="Разрешены только латинские, кириллические буквы, знаки дефиса и пробелы">
        <span class="popup__error description-input-error"></span>
        <button type="submit" class="button popup__button">Сохранить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

Функции открытия и закрытия попапов:
//открытие попап
export const openModal = (popupElement) => {
    popupElement.classList.add('popup_is-opened');
    document.addEventListener('keydown', closeByEsc);
};

//закрытие попап
export const closeModal = (popupElement) => {
    popupElement.classList.remove('popup_is-opened');
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', closeByEsc);
};  

Функция очистки ошибок валидации
export const clearValidation = (formElement, validationConfig) => {
    const inputList = Array.from(formElement.querySelectorAll(validationConfig.inputSelector));
    const buttonElement = formElement.querySelector(validationConfig.submitButtonSelector);
    inputList.forEach((inputElement) => {
        hideInputError(formElement, inputElement, validationConfig);
    });
    toggleButtonState(inputList, buttonElement, validationConfig);
};


Возможно оно не знает теперь про параметры formEditProfile и validationConfig . Просто идет вызов с NULL параметрами.

где была clearValidation до переноса? Добавь эту функцию в вопрос. Добавь функцию renderLoading. Добавь пример твоей разметки. Почему ты думаешь, что очистка ошибок перестала работать? Что происходит в методах openModal, closeModal?

добавь в вопрос код clearValidation. Как ты проверяешь, что ошибки остаются, если ты очищаешь ошибки только когда форма отправилась, а значит ошибок не было?

@Grundy добавила

Как ты проверяешь, что ошибки остаются

Разобралась… все работало, просто в голове не уложилось требование ревьюера. Что ошибки должны очищаться при успешном сабмите, а он у меня активен только в том случае, когда валидация успешна. Поэтому ошибки не очищались
